# In WPF, how to increase the thickness of ant in DataGrid from codeplex?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, navigation, cell, arrow-keys

I am using DataGrid for WPF from codeplex. The grid seems to be wonderful. Recently I noticed that the ant shown in the DataGrid while I am using arrow keys, there is a dotted ant that is displayed which is not very clear to the user. Sample shown below.
**The ant is now present around cell which has the value 4. It is dotted lines but not very clear**.

[image]

I wanted to know how can I increase the thickness of ant shown in this grid.

Comment: 'ant'? What do you mean? The border?

Comment: @Emo - yes .. The dotted border around 4 I have changed the screenshot now

Answer (score 0):

You can override that behavior of dotted focus by overriding `DataGridCell.FocusVisualStyle`.